# Magento 2.4 Rest API need to show filters related search result

Tags: magento2, rest-api, filter, search

Following code fetch the products based on search keyword but the issue is filtering showing all instead of the search result page.

I want filters should be shown only related to the search result page only.

```
   //Code for fetch products based on search term.    
    $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeid);
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $filterBuilder = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder');
    $searchCriteriaBuilder = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder');
    $searchInterface = $objectManager->get('Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface');
    $filterGroupBuilder = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder');

    $search_criteria = $searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
    $search_criteria->setRequestName("quick_search_container");
    $filter = $filterBuilder->setField('search_term')
    ->setValue($q)
    ->setConditionType("like")
    ->create();
    $filterGroup = $filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($filter)->create();
    $search_criteria->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup]);
    $resultx = $searchInterface->search($search_criteria);
    //var_dump($resultx); exit;

    $totalSearchResults = $resultx->getTotalCount();
    
    $products = $resultx->getItems();        

    if(count($products) == 0)
    {
      echo json_encode(array('status' => false,'message' => 'No data found'));exit;            
    }
    
    $product_data = array();
    foreach ($products as $pro) {
        //echo $product->getId(); exit;
        $product = $this->_productRepositoryFactory->create()->getById($pro->getId(),false,$storeid);                                                          
        $product_data[] = array(
        'product_id' => $product->getData('entity_id'),
        'sku' => $product->getData('sku'),
        'currency' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
        'type' => $product->getData('type_id'),
        'visibility' => $product->getData('visibility'),
        'status' => $product->getData('status'),
        'url_key' => $product->getData('url_key'),
        'url_path' => $product->getData('url_path'),
        'image' => $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')->getUrl(),
        'is_in_stock' => $this->getStockStatus($pro->getId()),
        'price' => $product->getData('price'),
        'special_price' => $product->getData('special_price')

        );
        
    }

    //Code for filter.
    $rootCategoryId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
    $category = $this->_categoryFactory->create()->setStoreId($storeid)->load($rootCategoryId);
    $filterableAttributes = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList::class);
    $layerResolver = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver::class);
    $layer = $layerResolver->get();
    $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
    $filterList = $objectManager->create(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList::class,
        [
            'filterableAttributes' => $filterableAttributes
        ]
    );
    $collection = $layer->getProductCollection();
    $allFilters = $filterList->getFilters($layer);
    $activeFilters = $this->_appApiHelperData->getFilters($allFilters,$storeid);

    $returnArray['total_count'] = count(array_unique($product_data,SORT_REGULAR));
    $returnArray['product_data'] = $product_data;
    $returnArray['filters'] = $activeFilters;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.4.1, I have implemented the below code for fetching products based on search terms and filters based on search results.

```
<?php
namespace YourModule\Appapi\Model\Search;

use YourModule\Appapi\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface; 
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface;
use Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\Data\StockItemInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image;
use Magento\Framework\Api\FilterBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;

class SearchResult implements SearchResultInterface
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $imageHelper;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_appApiHelperData;
    protected $_stockItemRepository;
    protected $_stockRegistryInterface;
    protected $filterBuilder;
    protected $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $filterGroupBuilder;
    protected $searchInterface;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        Image $imageHelper,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistryInterface,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Helper\Data $pricingHelper,
        \YourModule\Appapi\Helper\Data $appApiHelperData,
        FilterBuilder $filterBuilder,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        FilterGroupBuilder $filterGroupBuilder,
        SearchInterface $searchInterface        
    )
    {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->imageHelper = $imageHelper;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_appApiHelperData = $appApiHelperData;
        $this->_stockRegistryInterface = $stockRegistryInterface;;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->filterBuilder = $filterBuilder;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->filterGroupBuilder = $filterGroupBuilder;
        $this->searchInterface = $searchInterface;        

    }

    public function getSearchResult($q,$storeid)
    {   
        try{
            //Code for validations.
            if($storeid == '')
            {
                echo json_encode(array('code' => 200, 'status' => false, 'message' => 'Store id parameter should not be empty.'));
                exit;
            }
            if(!is_numeric($storeid))
            {
                echo json_encode(array('code' => 200, 'status' => false, 'message' => 'Store id parameter accept only numbers.'));
                exit;            
            }            
            if($q == '' || strpos($q, '@') !== false || strpos($q, '.com') !== false){
                $response = [
                    'status' => (bool)false,
                    'code' => 404,
                    'message' => __('Please enter a valid search keyword.')
                ];          
                echo json_encode($response);
                exit;
            }

        //Code for fetch products based on search term.    
        $this->_storeManager->setCurrentStore($storeid);
        $search_criteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $search_criteria->setRequestName("quick_search_container");
        $filter = $this->filterBuilder->setField('search_term')
        ->setValue($q)
        ->setConditionType("like")
        ->create();
        $filterGroup = $this->filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($filter)->create();
        $search_criteria->setFilterGroups([$filterGroup]);
        $search_result = $this->searchInterface->search($search_criteria);
        $totalSearchResults = $search_result->getTotalCount();        
        $products = $search_result->getItems();        
        if(count($products) == 0)
        {
          echo json_encode(array('status' => false,'message' => 'No data found'));exit;            
        }
        $product_data = array();
        foreach ($products as $pro)
        {
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($pro->getId(),false,$storeid);
            $product_data[] = array(
            'product_id' => $product->getData('entity_id'),
            'sku' => $product->getData('sku'),
            'currency' => $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode(),
            'type' => $product->getData('type_id'),
            'visibility' => $product->getData('visibility'),
            'status' => $product->getData('status'),
            'url_key' => $product->getData('url_key'),
            'url_path' => $product->getData('url_path'),
            'image' => $this->imageHelper->init($product, 'product_page_image_medium')->getUrl(),
            'is_in_stock' => $this->getStockStatus($pro->getId()),
            'price' => $product->getData('price'),
            'special_price' => $product->getData('special_price')
            );            
        }

        //Code for filter.
        $allAggregations = $search_result->getAggregations();
        $buckets = $allAggregations->getBuckets();        
        $activeFilters = $this->getFilters($buckets,$storeid);

        $returnArray['total_count'] = count(array_unique($product_data,SORT_REGULAR));
        $returnArray['product_data'] = $product_data;
        $returnArray['filters'] = $activeFilters;

        if(empty($product_data)){              
            echo json_encode(array('status' => false,'message' => 'No data found'));
            exit;
        }else{                
            $response = [
                'status' => (bool)true,
                'code' => 200,
                'message' => 'Success',
                'data' => $returnArray
            ];          
            echo json_encode($response, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
            exit;             
        }       


        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo json_encode(array('status' => (bool)false, 'message' => $e->getMessage()));
            exit;
        }
    }

     /**
     * get stock status
     *
     * @param int $productId
     * @return bool 
     */
    public function getStockStatus($productId)
    {
        /** @var StockItemInterface $stockItem */
        $stockItem = $this->_stockRegistryInterface->getStockItem($productId);
        $isInStock = $stockItem ? $stockItem->getIsInStock() : false;
        return $isInStock;
    }     
}
```

Fetch Filters based on the search results page.

```
<?php
namespace YourModule\Appapi\Helper;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Config;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $eavConfig;
    
    public function __construct(
        Config $eavConfig
        ){
        $this->eavConfig                = $eavConfig;
    }
    
    /*
     * Function: getFilters
     * Author: Jitendra Patel
     * Request Params: $filters,$storeid
     * Response Params: All Filters array or error message.
     */
    public function getFilters($buckets,$storeid)
    {
        $finalFilters = array();
        foreach($buckets as $bucket)
        {
            if($bucket->getName() == 'category_bucket')
            {
                continue;
            }
            $attribute_code = '';             
            $filters = array();
            $attribute_code = str_replace('_bucket','', $bucket->getName());
            foreach($bucket->getValues() as $value)
            {
             //code for fetch the attribute option value by option id.
             $metrics = $value->getMetrics();
             if(!empty($metrics['value']))
             {
                $option_id = $metrics['value'];             
                $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code);
                $optionlabel =  $attribute->getSource()->getOptionText($option_id);
                $filters['code']  = $attribute_code;
                $filters['name']  = $optionlabel;
                $filters['value'] = $metrics['value'];
                $filters['count'] = $metrics['count'];
             }
             $finalFilters[$attribute_code][] =     $filters;
            }            
        }
        if(empty($finalFilters))
        {
          $message = "Data not found";
          return $message;
        }
        else
        {
          return $finalFilters;
        }
    }
}
```